# Using Same "From" Email Address with Different Names

Tags: email, smtp, email-headers

We have a script that sends emails out. We want to personalize the "From" email address for outgoing emails, so that the email is being sent from the email address of the user sending it, even if we don't have their SMTP credentials to send the email from that user.

The script connects to an SMTP server to send the emails, we'd like to understand the best option for sending the emails, while ensuring the emails don't end up in Spam or Junk folders.

The options that we understand so far are:

**Option 1:**

- Send the emails with a common email address that we have SMTP credentials for, but change the name each time. Also set the actual corporate email address as the Reply-to: header.

Example headers:

- From: John Doe < my-generic-email@smtp-email.com >
- From: Jane Doe < my-generic-email@smtp-email.com >
- From: Joe Smith < my-generic-email@smtp-email.com >

We're not sure if there are consequences to changing the display name each time we send the email, like ending up on blacklists or identified as possible phishing.

**Option 2:**

Setting the From: as the actual email address we want it to appear that it came from.

- From: John Doe < john-doe@corporate-email.com >
- From: Jane Doe < jane-doe@corporate-email.com >
- From: Joe Smith < joe-smith@corporate-email.com >

Our understanding is that this is bad practice and most email servers will drop the email as a phishing attempt.

Are there any other options available for us to have the personalized "From" field while connecting to a common SMTP mail server / account?

Also note that we are connecting to a different domain for the SMTP server than the corporate email addresses are from.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. Are you looking for a stable "From:" header with a different Reply-To: for each email? That's perfectly legitimate.

Comment: "we are connecting to a different domain for the SMTP server" is going to be a problem unless the other domain is listed as a permitted sender in your SPF record.

Answer (score -2):

- You could find a group name like *support* or *xyz-department* in order to get around your problem.
- Option 1 should not be a problem and work fine, I don't think that mail service providers keep a record of which clear name is associated with which mail address in the mail headers of the mails that pass their servers. That would seem paranoid to me. I had a mail account once whiches from field changed quite often, because I changed it frequently and because my mail clients on different machines were configured inconsistently and it worked perfectly fine.
- I think option 2 is indeed bad practice and you should be honest in the mail header.

You mentioned that the hostname of your smtp server deviates from the hostname in the from field. This is no problem. Email is designed to be able to be forwarded from one mail transfer agent (mail server) to anoter to another to... Just make sure that all servers are configured correctly so that their hostname matches the dns entry pointing towards them and you may want to make sure, the reverse dns is set, too.

Still, you seem to pursue a rather uncommon strategy. Usually, every user should have his*her own smtp login credentials and what you plan seems to be fooling the recipient that he*she received mail from different people who are only one (one script) in the end.

Comment: You seem to ignore the massive problems this is going to have with popular antifforgery and antispam technologies. There was a time when email forgery was commonly tolerated, but those days are long gone.

Comment: It seems plausible that this will cause problems with the named technologies. But will it, though? I remember lots of support departments which share one common e-mail (sender) address and it works fine. As I mentioned, it worked fine for me, too. Also, email is indeed designed to forward from server to server and this is heavily used (e. g. at my university's mailing lists, also email forwarding is quite a usual thing.)